# How to make function from a list of tuples in Python?

Tags: python, function, tuples

I'd like to make a function using the list of tuples, from the first element to the second element,

```
Tuplelist = [(1, 17), (2, 13), (3, 17), (4, 4), (5, 12), (6, 10), (7, 20), (18, 36), (22, 12), (23, 39)]
```

I want the following result :

```
func(1)=17
func(2)=13
func(3)=17
func(4)=4
...
```

It seems easy but I can't find relevant questions in the web. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Could it be that you need something something simple like a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, this requires just a dictionary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func(item):
    return dict(Tuplelist)[item]
```

or better, if you do not want to create the dictionary every time you call the function,

```
dictTuplelist = dict(Tuplelist)
def func(item):
    return dictTuplelist[item]

print func(1), func(2), func(3)
# 17 13 17
```

Answer (score 0):

if that is all the values-result that you are going to handle, then a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) is what you need

```
>>> Tuplelist = [(1, 17), (2, 13), (3, 17), (4, 4), (5, 12), (6, 10), (7, 20), (18, 36), (22, 12), (23, 39)] 
>>> my_map = dict(Tuplelist)
>>> my_map[1]
17
>>> my_map[5]
12
>>> my_map[23]
39
```

if you want to make a function of it is a simple as

```
def my_fun(key):
    return dict(Tuplelist)[key]
```

or some other variation like

```
def my_fun(key):
    Tuplelist = dict([(1, 17), (2, 13), (3, 17), (4, 4), (5, 12), (6, 10), (7, 20), (18, 36), (22, 12), (23, 39)] )
    return Tuplelist[key]
```

or

```
MyValues = dict([(1, 17), (2, 13), (3, 17), (4, 4), (5, 12), (6, 10), (7, 20), (18, 36), (22, 12), (23, 39)] )

def my_fun(key):
    return MyValues[key]
```

anyway if that is all you need, I would use the dictionary directly rather that making a function that do the same in a more limiting way.

You can also do a simple linear search in the list, but this lose in the speed that a dictionary offer

```
Tuplelist = [(1, 17), (2, 13), (3, 17), (4, 4), (5, 12), (6, 10), (7, 20), (18, 36), (22, 12), (23, 39)] 

def my_func(key):
    for k,v in Tuplelist:
        if k == key:
            return v
```